# Flex-grow does not work in Angular for <router-outlet>

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

I create a web application with Angular. I wanted to make a footer that will be at the bottom of the page. If the content of the page was small, the footer would still be at the bottom, not in the middle of the page.
For this, I wrote code to push the contents of the  `<router-outlet>` directive down the page. But unfortunately it doesn't work.

This my code in css (code from the styles.css file):

```
#portal-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}

router-outlet {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

app-menu, router-outlet, app-footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

This is the content of my app.component.html file:

```
<div id="portal-wrapper">
  <app-menu></app-menu>
  <div id="portal">
      <div class="container">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <div class="row">
          <app-footer></app-footer>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Theoretically, the content should be pushed down (more precisely, the empty space below it) so that the footer is at the bottom of the page.   `flex-grow: 1;` for  `<app-menu>` works and pushes  `<router-outlet>` down. Any suggestions why  `<router-outlet>` doesn't push footer down?

Comment: You would most likely need to add: `display: flex;` to the router outlet tag.

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Comment: Just FYI - your router content is actually rendered after the outlet in the DOM, not inside of it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

div with `portal-wrapper` has two child i.e. `<app-menu>` and div `portal`, when make `portal-wrapper` into a flexbox you can use `flex-grow: 1` only for its child.

> `flex-grow: 1;` for `<app-menu>` works and pushes `<router-outlet>` down.

It's actually pushing the div `portal` down and not just the `<router-outlet>`

You should make div `container` into flexbox and add `flex-grow: 1` to `<router-outlet>`.